# Shell script to send email

Tags: linux, email, shell, scripting

I am on linux machine and I monitor a process usage. Most of the time I will be away from my system and I have access to internet on my device. So I planned to write a shell-script that can mail me the output of the process.

Is it possible?

If so how to make a shell-script send me mail?

Please provide a snippet to get started.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Yes it works fine and is commonly used:

```
$ echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" someone@somewhere.com
```

Comment: $ echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" -a "attachment file" someone@somewhere.com

for sending files

Comment: Where can I find the preset tutorial for this command? As to execute this command, I need to configure something.

Comment: @Zen Well you'll need to have your local MTA configured.

Comment: Don't forget to install the mail program first: `sudo apt-get install mailutils`

Comment: I have installed mailutils. This command is working for my local  PC however not working for remote server. Also remote system is not showing any error or success message. My remote system is on AWS EC2.

Comment: What will the receiver see in the `From` field? Who will be the sender in this case?

Comment: @user2513149 It will be the user invoking the commands.  Fullname will be retrieved from `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @trojanfoe so will it be in a form of `user@hostname`? Which hostname will be used if the server has multiple domains?

Comment: @user2513149 That's all part of the MTA configuration, so can be whatever the admin set-up.

Comment: it will be nice to include in the answer that mailutils should be installed and configured!

Answer (score 32):

Basically there's a program to accomplish that, called "mail". The subject of the email can be specified with a -s and a list of address with  -t. You can write the text on your own with the echo command:

```
echo "This will go into the body of the mail." | mail -s "Hello world" you@youremail.com
```

or get it from other files too:

```
mail -s "Hello world" you@youremailid.com < /home/calvin/application.log
```

mail doesn't support the sending of attachments, but Mutt does:

```
echo "Sending an attachment." | mutt -a file.zip -s "attachment" target@email.com
```

Note that Mutt's much more complete than mail.
You can find better explanation [here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/)

PS: thanks to @slhck who pointed out that my previous answer was awful. ;)

Comment: Stackoverflow should be self contained - it would have taken you the same amount of time to copy/paste the URL of that site and to copy/paste the one-liner @Ashwin asked for.

Comment: @slhck: Probably the full page is better than one or two lines and there's explained better than I would do. Mine isn't surely the best answer but downvote it is quite unfair since it provides the same information of any other answer.

Comment: This has been a long discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers - Even if it provides the same information, you could have digested it and cited your source.

Comment: @slhck: I agree with that, rarely I give only a link. But I thought, "a link is better than nothing", in fact I've never sent email in this way, just wanted to be helpful. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, I just brought it up because the answer to the original question is just a one-liner. Please edit your answer somehow, then I'll upvote again! Interestingly, the link you posted does not even load for me here.

Comment: @slhck: edited. Thanks for your comments, there's always room for improvements. ;)

Comment: if "mutt -s 'bla bla' -a /tmp/file target@mail.com" use -c flag in front of target@mail.com

Answer (score 7):

`sendmail` works for me on the mac (10.6.8)

```
echo "Hello" | sendmail -f my@email.com my@email.com
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mail -s "Your Subject" your@email.com < /file/with/mail/content
```

(`/file/with/mail/content` should be a plaintext file, not a file attachment or an image, etc)

Comment: Does this work with binary files?  I think I've had to use mutt before to do all the binary file encoding in the past.

Comment: You mean when trying to send a file as a mail attachment? You're right about this, of course. I meant text files only.

Comment: Yes! @slhck meant text files only. 'mail' cannot make attachments to user.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x
LANG=fr_FR

# ARG
FROM="foo@bar.com"
TO="foo@bar.com"
SUBJECT="test é"
MSG="BODY éé"
FILES="fic1.pdf fic2.pdf"

# http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions
SUB_CHARSET=$(echo ${SUBJECT} | file -bi - | cut -d"=" -f2)
SUB_B64=$(echo ${SUBJECT} | uuencode --base64 - | tail -n+2 | head -n+1)

NB_FILES=$(echo ${FILES} | wc -w)
NB=0
cat <<EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
From: ${FROM}
To: ${TO}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=frontier
Subject: =?${SUB_CHARSET}?B?${SUB_B64}?=

--frontier
Content-Type: $(echo ${MSG} | file -bi -)
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

${MSG}
$(test $NB_FILES -eq 0 && echo "--frontier--" || echo "--frontier")
$(for file in ${FILES} ; do
        let NB=${NB}+1
        FILE_NAME="$(basename $file)"
        echo "Content-Type: $(file -bi $file); name=\"${FILE_NAME}\""
        echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
        echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"${FILE_NAME}\""
        #echo ""
        uuencode --base64 ${file} ${FILE_NAME}
        test ${NB} -eq ${NB_FILES} && echo "--frontier--" || echo 
"--frontier"
done)
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest solution would of course be to pipe the output into mail:

```
vs@lambda:~$ cat test.sh
sleep 3 && echo test | mail -s test your@address
vs@lambda:~$ nohup sh test.sh
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

I guess `sh test.sh &` will do just as fine normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
top -b -n 1 | mail -s "any subject" your_email@domain.com
```