# Sending a mail from a linux shell script

Tags: linux, email, shell, sendmail

I want to send an email from a Linux Shell script. What is the standard command to do this and do I need to set up any special server names?

Comment: Try asking on Superuser [http://superuser.com/ ] or, better yet, Unix and Linux SE [http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script to send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283/shell-script-to-send-email)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If the server is well configured, eg it has an up and running MTA, you can just use the mail command.

For instance, to send the content of a file, you can do this:

```
$ cat /path/to/file | mail -s "your subject" your@email.com
```

`man mail` for more details.

Comment: What does 'mta' mean here, is there a full name or a link? As a beginner, that's what I want to know. As I lack of experience to do that.

Comment: @Zen MTA stands for Mail transport agent. postfix, sendmail, qmail etc

Comment: @Zen for the most part, you can consider MTA to mean SMTP or IMAP server.

Comment: If you're not sure how to install/configure and you're on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install mailutils` and select _Internet site: Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP._.

Answer (score 94):

If you want a clean and simple approach in bash, and you don't want to use `cat`, `echo`, etc., the simplest way would be:

```
mail -s "subject here" email@address.com <<< "message"
```

`<<<` is used to redirect standard input. It's been a part of bash for a long time.

Comment: echo -e "Some\nMultiline and tab\t msg"|mail -s "subject" your@email.com

Comment: `cat << END` ... `END | mail -s "subject" test@example.com`

Comment: Hey, this worked great for me, thanks! How would I specify multiple addresses to deliver to?

Comment: @E.Owen You can use the -t option to send to multiple addresses separated by spaces

Answer (score 29):

If both exim and ssmtp are running, you may enter into troubles. So if you just want to run a simple MTA, just to have a simple smtp client to send email notifications for insistance, you shall purge the eventually preinstalled MTA like *exim* or *postfix* first and reinstall ssmtp.

Then it's quite straight forward, configuring only 2 files (revaliases and ssmtp.conf) - See ssmtp doc - , and usage in your bash or bourne script is like :

```
#!/bin/sh  
SUBJECT=$1  
RECEIVER=$2  
TEXT=$3  

SERVER_NAME=$HOSTNAME  
SENDER=$(whoami)  
USER="noreply"

[[ -z $1 ]] && SUBJECT="Notification from $SENDER on server $SERVER_NAME"  
[[ -z $2 ]] && RECEIVER="another_configured_email_address"   
[[ -z $3 ]] && TEXT="no text content"  

MAIL_TXT="Subject: $SUBJECT\nFrom: $SENDER\nTo: $RECEIVER\n\n$TEXT"  
echo -e $MAIL_TXT | sendmail -t  
exit $?
```

Obviously do not forget to open your firewall output to the smtp port (25).

Comment: Where can I change the port number in this script? In my server smtp port works over 8181.

Comment: I would not do this in this shell otherwise you will get stucked sooner or later. You might do it in the config file : See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132731

Comment: Why are newlines being ingored if I make simple echo $MAIL_TXT?

Comment: @Marko : Pls see man echo with -e option : enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Comment: Sorry, did mis the -e parameter

Answer (score 10):

Another option for in a bash script:

```
mailbody="Testmail via bash script"
echo "From: info@myserver.test" > /tmp/mailtest
echo "To: john@mywebsite.test" >> /tmp/mailtest
echo "Subject: Mailtest subject" >> /tmp/mailtest
echo "" >> /tmp/mailtest
echo $mailbody >> /tmp/mailtest
cat /tmp/mailtest | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

- The file `/tmp/mailtest` is overwritten everytime this script is used.
- The location of sendmail may differ per system.
- When using this in a cron script, you have to use the absolute path for the sendmail command.

Comment: downvoted because more than one process could call the script at the same time. This could cause corrupt/incorrect tmp file.  Also the /tmp file is not overwritten each time this is used - it actually grows with each email containing all previous emails inside.  Not good.

Comment: The first write to /tmp/mailtest is an overwrite so it will remove whatever was in there previously. Still, this method is not ideal for the other reasons you have described.

Answer (score 10):

## SEND MAIL FROM LINUX TO GMAIL

**USING POSTFIX**

**1:** **install software**

Debian and Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install postfix mailutils
```

OpenSUSE:

```
zypper update && zypper install postfix mailx cyrus-sasl
```

Fedora:

```
dnf update && dnf install postfix mailx
```

CentOS:

```
yum update && yum install postfix mailx cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-plain
```

Arch Linux:

```
pacman -Sy postfix mailutils
```

FreeBSD:

```
portsnap fetch extract update

cd /usr/ports/mail/postfix

make config
```

in configaration select SASL support

```
make install clean

pkg install mailx
```

**2. Configure Gmail**

/etc/postfix. Create or edit the password file:

```
vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

i m using vim u can use any file editer like nano, cat  .....

**>Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS,Debian, OpenSUSE, Arch Linux:**

add this

where user replace with your *mailname* and password is your gmail *password*

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    user@gmail.com:password
```

**Save and close** the file  and Make it accessible only by root: *becouse its an sensitive content which contains ur password*

```
chmod 600 /usr/local/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

**>FreeBSD:**

directory /usr/local/etc/postfix.

```
vim /usr/local/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Add the line:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    user@gmail.com:password
```

Save and Make it accessible only by root:

```
chmod 600 /usr/local/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

**3. Postfix configuration**

configuration file main.cf

6 parameters we must set in the Postfix

**Ubuntu, Arch Linux,Debian:**

edit

```
 vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

modify the following values:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

**smtp_sasl_security_options** which in configuration will be **set to empty**, to ensure that **no Gmail-incompatible security options** are used.

save and close

as like for

**OpenSUSE:**

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

modify

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
```

it also requires  configuration of file **master.cf**

modify:

```
vim /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

as by uncommenting this line(remove #)

```
#tlsmgr unix - - n 1000? 1 tlsmg
```

save and close

**Fedora, CentOS:**

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

modify

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**FreeBSD:**

```
vim /usr/local/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

modify:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/mail/certs/cacert.pem
```

save and close this

**4. Process Password File:**

**Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, OpenSUSE, Arch Linux,Debian:**

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

for **freeBSD**

```
postmap /usr/local/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

**4.1) Restart postfix**

**Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, OpenSUSE, Arch Linux,Debian:**

```
systemctl restart postfix.service
```

for **FreeBSD:**

```
service postfix onestart
nano /etc/rc.conf
```

add

```
postfix_enable=YES
```

save then run to start

```
service postfix start
```

**5. Enable "Less Secure Apps" In Gmail**
using help of below link

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

**6. Send A Test Email**

```
mail -s "subject" recever@domain.com
```

press enter

add body of mail as your wish **press enter** then press **ctrl+d** for proper termination

if it not working **check the all steps** again and **check** if u enable "*less secure app"* in your gmail

then restart postfix if u modify anything in that

for shell script create the .sh file and add 6 step command as your requirement

for example just for a sample

```
#!/bin/bash
REALVALUE=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=80

if [ "$REALVALUE" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
    mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' mailid@domainname.com << EOF
Your root partition remaining free space is critically low. Used: $REALVALUE%
EOF
fi
```

The script sends an email when the disk usage rises above the percentage specified by the THRESHOLD varialbe (80% here).

Comment: Shouldn't the name of this answer should be "SEND MAIL FROM LINUX TO recever@domain.com VIA GMAIL"?

Answer (score 9):

Generally, you'd want to use `mail` command to send your message using local MTA (that will either deliver it using SMTP to the destination or just forward it into some more powerful SMTP server, for example, at your ISP). If you don't have a local MTA (although it's a bit unusual for a UNIX-like system to omit one), you can either use some minimalistic MTA like [ssmtp](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/132006).

`ssmtp` is quite easy to configure. Basically, you'll just need to specify where your provider's SMTP server is:

```
# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required
# no MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
# The example will fit if you are in domain.com and you mailhub is so named.
mailhub=mail
```

Another option is to use one of myriads scripts that just connect to SMTP server directly and try to post a message there, such as [Smtp-Auth-Email-Script](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Email-Code/Smtp-Auth-Email-Script/), [smtp-cli](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli/), [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/), etc.

Comment: "ssmtp" was is installed on the machine so I was unable to try it but thanks anyway

Answer (score 6):

Admitting you want to use some smtp server, you can do:

```
export SUBJECT=some_subject
export smtp=somehost:someport
export EMAIL=someaccount@somedomain
echo "some message" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
```

Change `somehost`, `someport`, and `someaccount@somedomain` to actual values that you would use. 
No encryption and no authentication is performed in this example.

Comment: And what to do if `mailx` is not installed?

Answer (score 3):

you can use 'email' or 'emailx' command.

(1) $ vim /etc/mail.rc # or # vim /etc/nail.rc

```
set from = xxx@xxx.com #
set smtp = smtp.exmail.gmail.com #gmail's smtp server 
set smtp-auth-user = xxx@xxx.com #sender's email address
set smtp-auth-password = xxxxxxx #get from gmail, not your email account passwd
set smtp-auth=login #because if it is not sent from an authorized account, email will get to junk mail list.
```

(2)

```
$ echo "Pls remember to remove unused ons topics!" | mail -s "waste topics" -a a.txt developer@xxx.com #send to group user 'developer@xxxx.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mail` command does that (who would have guessed ;-). Open your shell and enter `man mail` to get the manual page for the `mail` command for all the options available.

Comment: I did that but there is no option to specify a server to use

Comment: That is part of your local mail transfer agent configuration, e.g. Sendmail or Postfix.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need an MTA. The SMTP protocol is simple enough to directly write it to your SMTP server. You can even communicate over SSL/TLS if you have the OpenSSL package installed. Check this post: https://33hops.com/send-email-from-bash-shell.html

The above is an example on how to send text/html e-mails that will work out of the box. If you want to add attachments the thing can get a bit more complicated, you will need to base64 encode the binary files and embed them between boundaries. THis is a good place to start investigating: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?418377-Send-Email-w-attachments-using-SMTP

Answer (score 2):

On linux, **mail** utility can be used to send attachment with option "-a". Go through man pages to read about the option. For eg following code will send an attachment :

*mail -s "THIS IS SUBJECT"  -a attachment.txt name@domain.com <<< "Hi Buddy, Please find failure reports."*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please read the info about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and modify accordingly. Enjoy SO ;-)