# How to send the output of a script by email with ksh

Tags: email, ksh

I have written a script that output `pdf` files and print some stuff on the console. 
I am looking to be able to

- send those files by email
- as well as the output of the console.

I am using a linux `redhat RHEL6` distro and `ksh` (I CAN'T use `bash`).

How can I do that ?

**EDIT**

The following is NOT working can you see why ??

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "coucou" > /tmp/mailmessage.txt
mutt -s "Test mail" -a /home/zo/Documents/scripts/test.txt me@gmail.com < /tmp/mailmessage.txt
```

Getting the following error

```
zo@Pavilion:~/Documents/scripts$ ./muttme.sh 
Can't stat me@gmail.com: No such file or directory
me@gmail.com: unable to attach file.
```

Comment: bash or ksh should not make a difference.  See also: [Sending a mail from a linux shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155923/sending-a-mail-from-a-linux-shell-script)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script to send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283/shell-script-to-send-email)