# How to send email on my shell script condition in jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

i had created a job and in build step i had given below mentioned shell script

```
# Shell script to monitor or watch the disk space
# It will send an email to $ADMIN, if the (free avilable) percentage 
# of space is >= 70% 
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# set admin email so that you can get email
# set alert level 70% is default

ALERT=70
EXCLUDE_LIST="/net|/home|devfs"
if [ "$EXCLUDE_LIST" != "" ] ; then
  df -H | grep -vE "^Filesystem|Users|${EXCLUDE_LIST}" | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
  #echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
    echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" > /Users/Shared/Jenkins/disk_space.txt
else
    echo "space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" > /Users/Shared/Jenkins/space.txt
  fi
done
fi
```

After this script executed the email need to be triggered in jenkins if the condition satisfied. otherwise job should run but email should not trigger.

Comment: is `mail or mutt or sendmail` commands useful here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a standard question on how to send an email from a shell script: Have a look at the following links.

[Shell script to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283/shell-script-to-send-email)

http://theos.in/shell-scripting/send-mail-bash-script/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bash-ksh-csh-sendingfiles-mail-attachments/

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to call another jenkins job within the if loop, using jenkins cli.
You can have another job configured which will trigger a mail with certain content. And that job will be triggered within the success part of your if loop
More info on jenkins CLI can be found at [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)
May be this will be helpful.