# need to send file content in tabular format in report on mail using shell script ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I need to put a file content in tabular format and send it in a report in mail via shell script
The file already contains information in tabular format, like below
Can anyone assist

> cat tbs_cust.log

Stat Type Tablespace                                 (GB)             Total

---

ONL  P    BL9_RATED_EVENT_D                         1,295            1,259
ONL  P    BL9_RATED_EVENT_IX                          840              840
ONL  P    HUGE_D                                    1,640              677
ONL  P    HUGE_IX                                     720              556
ONL  P    LARGE_D                                   1,430              136
ONL  P    LARGE_IX                                    479               50
ONL  P    MEDIUM_D                                    840              510
ONL  P    MEDIUM_IX                                   340              221
ONL  P    POOL_DATA                                 1,574              572
ONL  P    SMALL_D                                     810              139
ONL  P    SMALL_IX                                    456               47
ONL  P    SYSAUX                                       15                7
ONL  P    SYSTEM                                       10                4
ONL  U    UNDOTBS                                     210              175
ONL  P    USERS                                         0                0
ONL  T    TEMP                                        420              420
                                                          ----------------
sum                                                                  5,612

Answer (score 0):

first point:

> put a file content in tabular format

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"}' tbs_cust.log > tempTbsCust
```

Then you can delete the new file by moving it in the old one (if you don't needed it)
    mv tempTbsCust tbs_cust.log

> report in mail via shell script

you can easly use the `mail` command to send a mail.

you can check [Shell script to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283/shell-script-to-send-email)
for more details

Regards

C