# Send Mail using cron job and shell script

Tags: shell, email, hadoop, cron, hive

I am using cron job to run my shell script after every 2 minutes.  My shell script contains pig and hive scripts.  I am searching the person with high risk using my hive query and i can get their email id from my hive table, i want to know if i can send mail to the person and how ?  I checked on the internet but not able to understand properly, it would be a great help if you guys help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658283 "Shell script to send email"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves my problem

```
$ echo "hello world" | mail -s "a subject" xxx@xxx.com
```